# how to append more div when refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I made a php script to get random data at one time. I use the refresh function to get more data . However, I only see 1 rows of data and that rows of data is being dynamically updated. I want to get more div from the feed. 
In other words, i want to append more div when refresh.

Here is my code below...

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Add new data</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
#result {
    width: 500px;
    height:500px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<pre id="result"></pre>

<script>
const result = document.getElementById("result");
continueExecution();
function continueExecution() {
    myVar = setInterval(updateServer, 1000);
}
function updateServer() {
    $.get({
            url: 'randomData.php',
            dataType: 'text',
            success: randomdata
        });
}

function randomdata(val) {
        $('#result').html(val);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

php script

```
<?php


$countryarr = array("UNITED STATES", "INDIA", "SINGAPORE","MALAYSIA","COLOMBIA","THAILAND","ALGERIA","ENGLAND","CANADA","CHINA", "SAUDI ARABIA");
$length = sizeof($countryarr)-1;
$random = rand(0,$length);
$random1 = rand(0,$length);

$random_srccountry = $countryarr[$random];
$random_dstcountry = $countryarr[$random1];
echo "<div class='data'>[X] NEW ATTACK: FROM [".$random_srccountry."] TO [".$random_dstcountry."]  </div>";
?>
```

my output from this code

```
[X] NEW ATTACK: FROM [MALAYSIA] TO [INDIA]
```

this data continue being updated

I want this output

```
[X] NEW ATTACK: FROM [MALAYSIA] TO [INDIA]  
[X] NEW ATTACK: FROM [ALGERIA] TO [CHINA]  
[X] NEW ATTACK: FROM [INDIA] TO [THAILAND]  
[X] NEW ATTACK: FROM [ALGERIA] TO [ALGERIA]
```

My question is how to append more div to the pre tag. Also is it the correct method to input the div in the php script....Please help me. thank you..

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add/append, then use `append()`:

`$('#result').append(val);`